# How can I implement SQL Server event listeners to trigger a Nodejs function?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I am new to nodejs and I would like to figure out how I could have event listeners from SQL Server trigger a Nodejs function on my server.

For instance, I would like my Nodejs server to receive notifications when there is any change (insert/update) for any given table in my database, which would then trigger an update of the UI on the client-side.

Comment: How did you manage to implement this? Did u use socket.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not altogether familiar with `SQL Server`, but I don't think you'll want to be using your DB server to POSTs to a webhook endpoint anyhow.

You're better off handling this functionality in your application code rather than on your database server.

The general idea is that it's your application that's going to be operating on the database anyhow, so you should have your application send out the the updates to your UI. A high-level step-by-step would look like so:

- Client sends request to server
- Server receives request and updates database
- Upon a successful update of the database, your server sends a response to the client
- The client receives the response from the server and adjusts the UI accordingly

Comment: its a real time IOT application am developing. AM using apache spark to handle the request and after processing wil update in the DB. I will be running nodejs server, for client interaction from UI. In a use case i would want to constantly update based on the new values in db.